# How to become a user at remote machine when running a role in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I know this has been discussed in other questions and I have tried various options but nothing seems to be solving my issue.

I am starting to learn Ansible and trying to run a playbook. I have one role which have tasks in it. I want to run the whole playbook as user john on remote machine. Playbook begins with a copying task. Everything was working fine till I started using become and become_user. I tried running the role as user john by specifying in major playbbok :

```
---
- hosts: target-machine.com
   roles:
   - role: installSoftware
     become: yes
     become_user: john
```

Then when executing the playbook, I run the following :

```
 ansible-playbook -s major.yml -K
```

which prompts me for

```
SUDO password:
```

I enter the password of user john which exists in the remote target machine. As soon as it starts running playbook, it hangs at the task which requires user as john and complains :

```
fatal: [target.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/home/john/software.zip): MODULE FAILURE"}
```

I also tried the following:

```
---
- hosts: target-machine.com
  become: yes
  become_user: john
  roles:
   - role: installSoftware
```

so as to run the whole playbook as user john. It again asks me for the SUDO password and then after 5 minutes complains:

```
fatal: [openam.ansible-target.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed":       true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "\r\nSorry, try again                           .\r\n[sudo via ansible, key=kchjtpjorgnvaksspqvgwzzkgtjnxsyv] password: \r\nsudo: 1 incorrect password attempt\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}
```

although the password I have entered is correct. On SO it was suggested to increase the SSH timeout which I did in ansible.cfg file:

```
 [ssh_connection]
 ssh_args = -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=1m
```

All I want to mirror is what I would run on target machine:

```
   su john
   Enter Password:
   john$
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `become` uses `sudo`, not `su`.  As a result, the password Ansible is prompting you for is the password of *the user you're logged-in as*, not the user you're changing to.  You can change this [by setting](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#directives) `become_method` to `su`.

If you want to always run all your tasks on that host as a different user, you probably instead want to set `ansible_user`.  See [the inventory documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) for more details on that.

Comment: Thanks for replying but when you said "the user you're logged-in as", are you referring to the user on control machine or the user on target machine? I tried the second method without any changes in ansible.cfg file and put john user password in but the same result. I also added a debug for shell: echo $USER without any become part and it showed "root", meaning it runs playbook as root user by default on target machine which I want to switch. Any pointers?

Comment: "Thanks for replying but when you said "the user you're logged-in as", are you referring to the user on control machine or the user on target machine?" -- the user on the target machine.  How did you set `ansible_user`?  It can be tricky sometimes to ensure it's in the right place and Ansible is picking it up.  If you add `-vvv` to your ansible command, it'll print out information about the ssh command, and if you look carefully you can see what user it's connecting as.

Comment: I ansible-playbook -s major.yml -K -vvv .. if I have ansible_user described in my hosts file as john then it does try to connect to the target machine as john on port 22 but then says that Authentication Failed   fatal: [machine-target.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication failed.", "unreachable": true}  Although I do put in the correct password.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the way that it is matching passwords? What will I need to do lets day if I want to login the target machine as the user that I am trying to switch to? Meaning not do any switching but just login as john to begin with in the target machine. This way I might be able to avoid using become ?

Comment: Can you normally (outside of Ansible) ssh to the machine as that user (`john`)?

Comment: Yes I was able to ssh as john user. As you had explained that become_method by default is sudo. Turns out that user `john` was not included in the sudoers file on target machine. Another thing that I had noticed was that when I tried to run `ansible all -m ping -u john` I received unreachable. Once the user was added to sudoers file on target machine was added, it became reachable by that command. Does this make sense? Am I understasnding it correctly?